# Build a docker volume based of an image

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose

Im trying to build a docker volume directly from a JS image through a bash command.

The difficulty here mostly lays on the fact that I want the contents of the volume to be the eval of a string.

The string itself is JS code that reads from a Kafka stream.

I know how to execute the bash command directly from a js file, However im a bit lost when it comes to what the command should look like:

TO clarify:
 - I want to specify the eval(string) as the code to run inside the container
 - I want to specify three environment files 
 - I want to run everything directly from a js file . 
 - This JS file is already dockerised in case it matters

I understand Stack overflow is not meant to give me answers, but I have looked everyone and im having a real hard time figuring out how to proceed. SO any pointers would be very appreciated

Comment: So, to clarify - you have some JS code that you get dynamically from somewhere and want to create a container and run that code in this container?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I need @georg

Comment: Are you able to provide a [mcve]? I'm having a difficult time understanding your goal and challenges from the question.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you can proceed like this:

1) create a docker image that contains everything is needed to run the js file (OS, node etc)

2) once you receive the js file, create a temporary directory on the local drive and copy that file to it

3) run the container, mount your local dir and tell the container to execute the file from there. The command can look like this

```
docker run \
   --mount type=bind,src=/your-temp-dir,dst=/temp-dir,readonly \
   --detach \
   your-docker-image-name \
   node /temp-dir/your-javascript-file.js
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ for more details.

Comment: the issues is that its not a js file but a string that contains js code. also how would I go about adding env vars?

Comment: I mean in theory I could just create a new file with the same bash and paste the string into that file no?

Comment: @lucasrodriguez: yes, you can write that string to a file (`fs.writeFileSync` in node). Env variables can be added when you create the image (ENV in the dockerfile), or right in the `run` command (`-e` option).

Comment: This looks very promising, just need one small clarification for me one last time: 

The image would be the one with all the dependencies the ports and so on.
And the command above would deploy a volume  based on that image or am I misunderstanding. 

Also the code where this is running is already dockerised would this be an issue?

Comment: @lucasrodriguez: yes, this image should contain everything you need to run the script (OS, packages, node.js, libs etc). The command creates a container from the image, runs a command in it and then stops it. No, it won't work from inside another docker container, it should be run on the host system.

Comment: so if the host disconnects, eg closes the application, so will the container right? 
The issue is this a bot so its not meant to stop running, ever, unless explicitly told to. Is there any way to run this in the back end based on a front end trigger?

Comment: Sure, you can keep the container running, but then your containerized app should have an endless loop,  listen to some communication channel (port, socket) and do something once it sees the data. In other words, you need a server.

Comment: How could I make it work from within another container? maybe as a sibling container?

Comment: or maybe theres some cleaver . way I haven't thought  of?

Comment: I guess it would be helpful to see a bigger picture. A little bit more about your architecture, tools you use and the ultimate goal of this particular assignment. Not sure if SO comments is the right place to discuss that though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you really need to dockerize the JS file. Rather what you can do is write the incoming stream (which is JS) to another file e.g. volume-creator.js and then call that file.

In this case your volume-creator.js should also include dependencies like node-docker which will make your docker commands easy and OS agnostic.

The reason I would avoid dockerizing the invoker JS is you may need some extra privileges to run docker commands within the container e.g you may need to mount the docker socket which can make your host OS and docker system vulnerable .