# Docker sibling containers to run a bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I want to use an inline js bash command to deploy a docker volume, from within a docker volume. I read this command would be useful:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

My understanding is this would launch a sibling container instead of a docker inside a docker. 
How ever im not sure at all about how this would look from a docker image and how this would help me launch the docker volume from within the endpoint, would a command along this lines work:

```
    docker run \
   --mount type=bind,src=/your-temp-dir,dst=/temp-dir,readonly \
   --detach \
   your-docker-image-name \
   node /temp-dir/your-javascript-file.js
```

Im a bit lost and would  very much appreciate some pointers to resources or clarification as to  what the best approach to this would be.

Comment: When you say “deploy a volume”, what specific operation are you trying to do?  Note that a container can’t do _any_ Docker operations without being able to get unrestricted root-level access to the host, so you need to be _very_ careful what you do with that socket bind-mounted.

Comment: I want to put a file with js code in a docker container . that will run in a loop for ever. I realise how **incredibly** dangerous this is. but Im trying to build a trading  bot management system where you can upload trading strategies from the front end. For personal use not commercially so I can skip this best practice.

Comment: You can’t build an image out of it?

Comment: Id like to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773548/build-a-docker-volume-based-of-an-image?noredirect=1#comment101982384_57773548 but from inside a container.